# Difference in months between two dates in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have two columns of dates that I wish to find the number of months between.

Each column is in YYYY-mm-dd format.

I have tried testing different approaches, but that all deals with converting number of days to months which I cannot due since different months have a different number of days.

```
  df=structure(list(group = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), min = structure(c(14610, 
  15737, 14610, 15737, 14610), class = "Date"), max = structure(c(15706, 
  16617, 15706, 16617, 15706), class = "Date")), .Names = c("group", 
  "min", "max"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @etienne You could leave you answer there, you replied before I posted the duplicate. It might still help the OP.

Comment: @LyzandeR: the same (and more detailed) answer is posted in your link so I thought it best to delete it